# Spark streaming saveAsTextFiles function

Tags: streaming, apache-spark

how to apply `saveAsTextFiles(prefix,[suffix])`
I have this :

```
        JavaDStream<String> hashTags = statuses
            .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
                public Boolean call(String word) {
                    return word.contains("#");
                }
            });
```

When i write hashTags.print() its work and i receive data in the terminal , what i  went to do is save this data in a text file with java .

Comment: Can you clarify your question: Do you need help on how to write to files on disk on the server-side or...?

Comment: i need to write to files on disk

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
hashTags.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("myoutput","txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is... but try this:

1. Create an RDD from original data source

   rdd2 = rdd1.filter(...)
2. rdd2.saveAsTextFile(...)

Answer (score 0):

saveAsTextFile function only can be implement by rdd spark. Related to ur code it would be like this:

```
JavaDStream<String> hashTags = statuses
 .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(String word) {
        return word.contains("#");
        }
  });
 hashTags.saveAsTextFile("location.txt");
```

sorry if i'm wrong..