# JavaDStream Pom Dependency

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Im trying to write a piece of Spark Streaming code in Java and I want to output my stream into another file. I created a JavaDStream called words, and I am able to call the method `words.print()`. However, when I use the method `words.saveAsTextFiles(arg,arg)` I get a `error: cannot find symbol` when I compile.

I noticed in the javadoc for JavaDStream the method only exists in version 1.1.1, so I am thinking I am not using the right versions of my dependencies in my pom file .. the dependencies are below.

```
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amit.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-examples-1.2.1.2.2.4.2-2-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is this correct? Is there another way I can output into my file? I think I can use `words.forEachRDD` and overriding the function and using the JavaRDD method saving into the text file. Will that work? Am I using the command wrong? Is there another wraparound that I can use? I eventually want to be able to output into a HDFS cluster.

I saw this post [Spark streaming saveAsTextFiles function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375655/spark-streaming-saveastextfiles-function) ... do I use `words.forEachRDD` to "create an RDD from the original data source"?

Please let me know what other information needed to help me solve this problem. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
        words.wrapRDD(null).saveAsTextFile(path)